# Why is Power Statistics showing grossly incorrect battery power?

Tags: 12.04, power-management, battery

- **`Energy when full - 231.7 Wh`**
- `Energy(design) - 81.2 Wh`

This also results in an incorrect value for `Percentage - 31.3%`

This also conflicts with `Time to full` field (Thankfully !)

[image]

I have never seen this difference before. Why is this happening ?

Can this damage the battery or my laptop in any way ?

My laptop is [Asus U32U - RX012D](http://in.asus.com/Notebooks/Superior_Mobility/U32U/#specifications).

---

### UPDATE :

Bug reported : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/1099039

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes, i was going to do that next. Just wanted to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: On second thought, while I'm glad you're reporting the bug, I think maybe we shouldn't close this question, since the information in the answer about why this doesn't constitute a risk to your computer could be valuable to other users. We may have other questions we close as duplicate of this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting as an answer as it needs some more explanation besides "close it - it's a bug!".*

> Why is this happening ?

This is a bug. Could be in the GUI, upower frontend or in the kernel. I can't tell really, but, go here:

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

> Can this damage the battery or my laptop in any way ?

No, Ubuntu does not control the power controller and in most cases it can't do anything with it besides reading states (exception here are Thinkpads with the fancy `thinkpad-smapi` module).

Comment: I had thought as much. However, the problem seems to have gone on reboot. Also, that was the first and only time i had seen this and i have made no recent changes to the system.

Comment: @AshRj That's another indication of it being a bug. :)

Comment: Shouldn't bugs be reproducible ?

Comment: Hard to reproduce bugs are still bugs. If they appear often and hard to catch some people call them "hairy bugs". :) Anyway, if you have it, you should include a path to reproduce, yes, but you'll probably be given advice what to do when it happens again for more information.